# Duplex channel in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin, xamarin.android, duplex

I'm creating in .Net/Mono an online service thats front-end will be on various mobile platform and may be back-end will be based on Windows Azure. To communicate with server I've prefered the most familiar for me WCF, and its seems to be better to use duplex channel (the traffic seems to be critical). But when I've tried to compile the application for Android (WCF client is in a portable libray) I've got an error:

```
Error   10  Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'System.ServiceModel.Duplex, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'System.ServiceModel.Duplex.dll'
   at Xamarin.Android.Tuner.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(List`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute() TaxiOnline.Android
```

It can be caused only by the line:

```
private readonly InstanceContext _callbackInstance;
```

Tell me please how can I configure Android application to eliminate this error. Duplex channel would be better but not as a platform-specific. I need a portable code for server communication. Current target API is 14 (for Android 4.0+).

Comment: not sure of Mono. But do you see 'System.ServiceModel.Duplex.dll' in references for your project?

Comment: I've missed one important thing in the description: the service module is a portable class library ('cause it needs to be shared in Android and iOS). So the reference is a portable subset, that uses profile 7 (excepting Android and iOS it includes .Net 4.5 and WinStore applications). May be a solution can be by profile configuration but i don't know how (the only other profile I could find is with Silverlight instead of WinStore, but it's much more reduced and has no important things as ReaderWriterLockSlim that I need at least in my client proxy for the server).

Comment: I've understand - there is no System.ServiceModel.Duplex.dll amoung all DLLs in %Program Files%\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid. For some reason System.ServiceModel.Duplex.dll is included in portable profile 7 for .Net 4.5, so it presents in the portable subset that in fact cannot be completely applied to Android (and also to iOS, the equivalent MonoTouch directory has no the DLL too).

Comment: Does portable profile 7 officially support mono? If no, then Microsoft can raise its hand. This looks like a gap in mono, or there might be something equivalent

Comment: I'm not sure about current state of parthnership of Microsoft with Xamarin, but I think such add-ons are Xamarin competence. But as I've found out yestarday 'cause MonoAndroid part of the framework really doesn't include System.ServiceModel.Duplex.dll I can only expect it in future versions of Xamarin.Android. By other hand I'm thinking about to migrate to Windows Azure Mobile Services after the preview version completion (I'm estimating this way now).

Answer (score 0):

In the [Mono project](http://www.mono-project.com/), the source code shown it supported the duplex channel.
The Xamarin.IOS and Xamarin.Android are based on Mono, But not sure what reason **Xamarin team just cut the duplex channel feature when create these 2 projects based on Mono.**

Even .Net core create after Xamarin so much late, but now .Net core already supported duplex channel in [Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform v5.2.0](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf). which mean, you still could use UWP or UWP with Xamarin.Forms create a duplex channel project. But Xamarin.IOS and Xamarin.Android still not.  Actually already some people asked about the duplex channel feature for a few years in [Xamarin forums](http://forums.xamarin.com).But the Xamarin team still ignoring it.Maybe too busy, or maybe that's a Microsoft style: everything too late for come or too late for change.

However, there is still some **people asking this feature on Bugzilla of Xamarin**, If you still have hope for this, you could vote it or discuss:[Request add WCF Duplex Channel support for Mono(for Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.IOS)](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=41392)

Also There is a discussion(with WCF and Xamarin team) about it: [Could you guys let some of the team members go to update WCF of Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS?](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/1688)